# php next occurring date with relative day time

Tags: php

I'm trying to find the next epoch date from a relative day/time (work shift).

```
foreach($shift->meta_value as $shift_day) {
    $start_string = $shift_day['day'] . ' ' . $shift_day['start_hour'] . ':' . $shift_day['start_min'] . $shift_day['start_meridian'];
    $showStart[$shift->post_id] = date('U', strtotime($start_string));

    $end_string = $shift_day['day'] . ' ' . $shift_day['end_hour'] . ':' . $shift_day['end_min'] . $shift_day['end_meridian'];
    $showEnd[$shift->post_id] = date('U', strtotime($end_string));
}

asort($showEnd);

$end = array();
foreach ($showEnd as $key => $val) {
    if (date("U", $val) > date("U")) {
        $end[$key] = $val;
}

asort($end);
```

If the day/time has already passed, it needs to find the next occurrence of it. When sorting the 'end' array, it's not giving me the correct value. Any ideas?

Comment: You should give a sample start value and expect result

Comment: You shouldn't walk away after asking a question. You miss your chance to answer questions people may have and now the chances of you getting an answer just got a lot smaller.

Comment: Thanks for the tip.
Basically I have a relative date - Monday 6pm. I'm turning this into a unix epoch value and sorting them. The problem is the strtotime function is not properly getting the NEXT occurring date of Monday 6pm. I have tried the additional This and Next arguments but it doesn't seem to be working as expected. Just curious if anyone has run across this and found a solution.